# change an attribute value of a XML file in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xmltextreader

how I can change the attribute "id" using my source code?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(@"C:\Users\1.xml");
        XmlNodeList elementList = reader.
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element: // The node is an element
                    {
                        reader.ReadToFollowing("command"); 
                        reader.MoveToAttribute("id");                         
                        Console.Write(reader.Value);
                        Console.WriteLine(" ");                    
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }           
        Console.Read();
    }
```

I saw some examples, but they have used another methods that don't work with mine. (I'm a noobie)

Comment: You're just using XmlReader - that's for reading, not changing. You'd be better off using LINQ to XML, but we can't tell really what you're trying to do at the moment.

Comment: i have a xml file, where I have to change values on different positions. easy example:
<command device="Tissue"id="10"></command>
<command device="Tissue"id="20"></command> ...
so I have to change numbering like id="0"id="1" and so on

Answer (score 1):

I would use LINQ to XML

```
XElement doc=XDocument.Load(path);
foreach(var element in doc.Descendants().Elements("command"))
{
element.Attribute("id").Value=yourValue;
}
doc.Save(path);
```

This would change each command element's id attribute

Comment: Why not use `Descendants("command")` instead of `Descendants().Elements("command")`?

Comment: (was long time away)
what library I've to use? its not enough using.linq; 
XElement is not recognized.

Comment: used System.Xml.Linq; and became an issue: cannot convert ...XDocument to XElelent.

Answer (score 1):

Code above didn't fly for me

this works thought

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(path);
    foreach(var element in doc.Descendants("command"))
    {
        element.Attribute("id").Value = id;
    }

doc.Save(path);
```

Hope this saves you some time.